# lifetime of variables and static arrays in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I heard that, in Fortran77, all local variables in a function are created at the beginning of the main program execution and exist during the whole runtime, rather than being created on entry to the function and being destroyed on exit. I do not know whether this is still true in newer Fortran. Is there any way that can test this out?
One test that meight help is to check whether variables retain their values between invocations. Here is a simple test:

```
  program main
  call p()
  call p()
  call p()
 end program main

 subroutine p()
  real :: a(3)
  a=a+1
  write(*,*) a(1), a(2), a(3)
 end subroutine p
```

My test using `gfortran` indicates array `a` retains its values between invocations, the same behavior as `save` attribute being used.
I am wondering whether this is a standard in Fortran Language or depends on compiler implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a test cannot prove anything. The fact that some garbage remains in the stack between two function invocations can be a pure coincidence.

Local function variables are only valid during the function invocation in which their value was defined. That is also true in Fortran 77. If the value should be retained, the variables hhave to be declared `SAVE`.

Comment: If the test indicates that every elements of a very large array retain their values between two function invocations, that test would prove someting, i.e., the lifetime of the local array is the whole execution rather than limited to the function invocation.

Comment: I am talking about the lifetime, but the second sentence of your reply talks about the scope.

Comment: @YoujunHu You are completely wrong, if the test indicates, that the elements retain their value, it proves absolutely nothing. That is just [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the data just remains there as invalid garbage, you are not allowed to read it evenif it was left in the memory. You are just lucky that the array happens to be static or that the stack happens to be laid out the same on each invocation.

Comment: @YoujunHu Your other comment is wrong as well. The remark about `SAVE` *is* about lifetime, not about scope. Only with `SAVE` the array remains to be valid even when it goes out of scope. Without `save` the value is unefined once the procedure returns.

Comment: Totally agree with you now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Fortran 77 didn't require support for recursion,  and implicit SAVE was fairly common. If you want to find out whether data are overwritten when ou of scope, at the very least you must call another procedure which may store data in the same address space before looking to see whether data happen to be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, we can try a program where some other routine (e.g.`foo()`) may be called between successive calls of `p()`:

```
program main
    call p()
    !  call foo()  ! (*)
    call p()
    !  call foo()  ! (*)
    call p()
end

subroutine p()
    real :: a(3)
    a = a + 1
    write(*,*) "a = ", a
end

subroutine foo()
    real :: b(3)
    b = b * 10
    write(*,*) "b = ", b
end
```

With the lines (*) commented, we get

```
 ! gfortran-8.2
 a =    1.00000000       4.74066630E+21   1.00000000    
 a =    2.00000000       4.74066630E+21   2.00000000    
 a =    3.00000000       4.74066630E+21   3.00000000

 ! PGI18.10
 a =     1.000000        1.000000        1.000000    
 a =     2.000000        2.000000        2.000000    
 a =     3.000000        3.000000        3.000000
```

while with the lines (*) uncommented, we get

```
 ! gfortran-8.2
 a =    1.00000000       4.74066630E+21   1.00000000    
 b =    10.0000000       4.74066641E+22   10.0000000    
 a =    11.0000000       4.74066641E+22   11.0000000    
 b =    110.000000       4.74066623E+23   110.000000    
 a =    111.000000       4.74066623E+23   111.000000

 ! PGI18.10
 a =     1.000000        1.000000        1.000000    
 b =     0.000000        0.000000        0.000000    
 a =     2.000000        2.000000        2.000000    
 b =     0.000000        0.000000        0.000000    
 a =     3.000000        3.000000        3.000000
```

(This is just an experiment/illustration of the behavior of local variables (i.e. not necessarily "SAVE-ed" as it might appear in a simpler case), and please see [the other answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55659254/3501546) for detailed explanations.)

Comment: When this is the accepted answer, could you at least add the actual answer to the question, in the interest of future visitors? Just a comment that those values changed is fine.

Comment: @VladimirF Hi, I've added a pointer to your answer (which I also think should be "accepted"). Indeed, mine is just for fun .. :) (It might be interesting to try other compilers as well, but unfortunately I don't have access atm.)